# What is the stochastic integral of $\frac{dW_t}{W_t}$

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Does anyone know the solution to the Ito integral with the scaling factor on $dW_t$ being $\frac{1}{w_t}$?  In other words what is:

$\int \frac{dW_t}{W_t}$  ?

It looks dangerously close to what mathemattical finance people do when they look at geometric Brownian motion, but they start with the assumption that the price, $S_t$ follows an exponential trajectory of the form:

$S_t=S_0e^{((\mu -\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t+\sigma W_t)}$

so, when they take the natural log the $e^{(-)}$ falls away.

My brain may just be failing, but I think this does not help find $\int \frac{dW_t}{W_t}$.

In fact, I am curious if there is a 'standard' (cookbook) way of getting the integral of any polynomial Brownian motin, i.e., $\int (W_t)^kdW_t$, but $k=-1$ is fine for now...

Answer (score 2):

On the particular case, $k=-1$, one shouldn't be surprised by this being problematic. Certainly, the hyperbola, $\frac{1}{x}$, is undefined at the origin. Therefore, it does not satisfy [the usual conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation#Existence_and_uniqueness_of_solutions) that guarantee the existence and uniqueness of a solution to the SDE, $\mathrm df(W_t) = \frac{1}{W_t}\mathrm dW_t,\ W_0=0$. This problem does not arise in finance since the stock price, $S$, cannot be zero.

On the cases of $k=0,1,2,\ldots$, a useful first step is the use of Ito's lemma to justify:

> $$
> \int\limits_{0}^{t} W_s^{k}\ \mathrm dW_s = \frac{1}{k+1}\left(W_t^{k+1} {}+{} {\bf 1}_{k>0}(k)\ {k+1\choose 2}\int\limits_{0}^{t}W_s^{k-1}\ \mathrm ds\right),
> $$

where the *r.h.s.* now casts the problem in terms of Riemann integrals. While, in general, determining the distributions of $\ ``\int\limits_{0}^{t}W_s^{k-1}\ \mathrm ds"$ can be involved, less ambitious goals, such as computing $\mathbb E[\int\limits_{0}^{t}W_s^{k}\ \mathrm dW_s]$, can be accomplished using this alternate form.

Comment: Yes, mathematically I agree on the existence and uniqueness.  But my application is finance and, as you note, $S_0=0$ is non-sensical in that context.  Having worked in research physics we often did not have a closed-form solution to the 'correct' PDEs, but having a solution in the neighborhood can make a problem more tractable.  Given that, any idea what the solution to $\int \frac{dW_t}{W_t}$ is?

Comment: @foobar, What is "a solution in the neighbourhood of a random variable"?

Comment: I knew you would ask...it is not a 'neighborhood' in the sense of topology.  In the work I did we needed to model coupling and transmission of oscillations of a (superconducting) cavity.  The geometry made simply applying Maxwell's equations too hard owing to boundary complexity.  Numeric PDE could be used, but even that was a chore.  In the end you solve for a simpler geometry based on idealizing and then perturbations that should have small effect, so you can then look empirically for what you want to find.  If your cavity is a slight ellipsoid, solve for a sphere and work from there.

Comment: @foobar, Thanks; I think I see where you are coming from, but not where you are going. Two points: 1) The usefulness of existence and uniqueness criteria is in providing confidence that seeking SDE solutions is not a futile task. I am not convinced that $\{\int_{0}^{t}\frac{dW_s}{W_s}\}_{0\leqslant t\leqslant T}$ is well-defined. 2) Assuming it exists, can you formally specify (i.e. in terms of a stochastic process/random variables) what you would consider to be an approximate solution to a random process?

Comment: My interest is in exploring the dynamics of a process where the notion of the process "running away" from the deterministic PDE does not occur.  In geometric Brownian motion the naive solution from discrete modeling always becomes something like $e^{(\alpha + \beta)t}$ when the deterministic PDE that looks 'the same' has solution $e^{\alpha t}$.  The 'Ito correction' takes out the $\beta$, as it were.  I am curious about a process where it has different dynamics.  In finance terms, a process where the realization under risk-neutral measure is above the deterministical (or modeled) path.

Comment: @foobar, Then I suggest: 1) asking a question on an application specific site like quant.stackexchange to determine the actual SDE (or SDE family) you are interested in. I think you need help in specifying the mathematical problem you are really interested in; 2) Once specified formally, asking about the solution of that SDE on this site. However, concerning the question you posted above, of what the distribution of $\int_{0}^{t}\frac{dW_s}{W_s}$ is, does my response answer that specific concern and direct you along further lines of inquiry?